# C switch not triggering

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char deci;
    int hours,min;

    printf("Enter a 12-hour time: ");
    scanf("%d:%d %c",&hours,&min,&deci);

    if(deci == 'PM'){
        switch(hours){
            case 1: printf("Equivalent 24-hour time: 13:%d",min); break;
            case 2: printf("Equivalent 24-hour time: 14:%d",min); break;
            case 3: printf("Equivalent 24-hour time: 15:%d",min); break;
            case 4: printf("Equivalent 24-hour time: 16:%d",min); break;
            case 5: printf("Equivalent 24-hour time: 17:%d",min); break;
            case 6: printf("Equivalent 24-hour time: 18:%d",min); break;
            case 7: printf("Equivalent 24-hour time: 19:%d",min); break;
            case 8: printf("Equivalent 24-hour time: 20:%d",min); break;
            case 9: printf("Equivalent 24-hour time: 21:%d",min); break;
            case 10: printf("Equivalent 24-hour time: 22:%d",min); break;
            case 11: printf("Equivalent 24-hour time: 23:%d",min); break;
            case 12: printf("Equivalent 24-hour time: 0:%d",min); break;
       }
    }
    else
        printf("Equivalent 24-hour time: %d:%d",hours,min);

    return 0;
}
```

Expected behavior:
    Enter a 12-hour time: 9:11 PM and print this Equivalent time: 21:11, and I get Equivalent time: 9:11. Why does the `if()` statement never evaluated true?

Comment: This should have *at least* one compiler warning. Fix it and you will notice your mistake. Listen to your compiler.

Answer (score 4):

You take input `char deci`. It's a single character.

Change the condition:

```
if(deci=='P') // only P is able to identify 'PM'. you can work with this single char
{
  //
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to read in `deci` as a string rather than as a single character.  Also note that you can't do a simple comparison on string constants, and that string constants are surrounded in double quotes, not single quotes.

```
char deci[5];
int hours,min;

printf("Enter a 12-hour time: ");
scanf("%d:%d %s",&hours,&min,deci);

if(strcmp(deci,"PM") == 0) {
...
```

Also, the output won't be quite what you expect even with that fix.  This should work:

```
if(strcmp(deci,"PM") == 0) {
    if (hours == 12) {
        printf("Equivalent 24-hour time: 12:%d",min);
    } else {
        printf("Equivalent 24-hour time: %d:%d",hours+12,min);
    }
} else {
    if (hours == 12) {
        printf("Equivalent 24-hour time: 0:%d",min);
    } else {
        printf("Equivalent 24-hour time: %d:%d",hours,min);
    }
}
```